# WPF UserControl with Binding Mode=OneWay

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

I am trying to make a sample WPF user control (maybe it would be better to say “developer control”) with bindable properties. My code consists of these files:

```
----- MainWindow.xaml -----
<Window x:Class="Test_Binding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:testBinding="clr-namespace:Test_Binding"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <testBinding:MyLabelledTextBox x:Name="MLTB" LabelText="My custom control: MyLabelledTextBox" Text="{Binding StringData, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

----- MainWindow.xaml.cs -----
using System.Windows;

namespace Test_Binding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = new MyDataObject();
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}

----- MyDataObject.cs -----
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices; // CallerMemberName
using System.ComponentModel; // INotifyPropertyChanged

namespace Test_Binding
{
    public class MyDataObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string stringData;
        public string StringData
        {
            get { return this.stringData; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.stringData)
                {
                    this.stringData = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public MyDataObject()
        {
            System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
            t.Interval = 10000;
            t.Elapsed += t_Elapsed;
            t.Start();
        }

        private void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.StringData = ((this.StringData ?? string.Empty).Length >= 4 ? string.Empty : this.StringData + "*");
        }

    }
}

----- MyLabelledTextBox.xaml -----
<UserControl x:Class="Test_Binding.MyLabelledTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <StackPanel Background="Yellow">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>   
        <Label x:Name="MLTBLabel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBox x:Name="MLTBTextBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="Yellow" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>

----- MyLabelledTextBox.xaml.cs -----
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Test_Binding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MyLabelledTextBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyLabelledTextBox : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LabelText", typeof(string), typeof(MyLabelledTextBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, MyLabelledTextBox.LabelTextPropertyChanged));
        public string LabelText
        {
            get { return (string)this.GetValue(MyLabelledTextBox.LabelTextProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(MyLabelledTextBox.LabelTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyLabelledTextBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, MyLabelledTextBox.TextPropertyChanged));
        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)this.GetValue(MyLabelledTextBox.TextProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(MyLabelledTextBox.TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public MyLabelledTextBox()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.MLTBLabel.DataContext = this;
            this.MLTBTextBox.DataContext = this;
            this.MLTBTextBox.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(this.MLTBTextBox_TextChanged);
        }

        private void MLTBTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = this.MLTBTextBox.Text; // transfer changes from TextBox to bindable property (bindable property change notification will be fired)
        }

        private static void LabelTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((MyLabelledTextBox)d).MLTBLabel.Content = (string)e.NewValue; // transfer changes from bindable property to Label
        }

        private static void TextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((MyLabelledTextBox)d).MLTBTextBox.Text = (string)e.NewValue; // transfer changes from bindable property to TextBox
        }
    }
}
```

There is an instance of the “MyDataObject” class with the property “StringData”, which is modified periodically using a timer. My user control is bound to its property “StringData”. If the binding in the “MainWindow.xaml” file is set as “TwoWay”, the user control keeps being updated, but if I use the “OneWay” binding, then the user control is updated a single time and then the “PropertyChanged” event of the instance of the “MyDataObject” class does not fire again, because suddenly it has no subscriber.

Why does the “OneWay” binding stop working after being invoked once ?
What code change would allow both the “TwoWay” and “OneWay” bindings to keep working ?

Comment: When you have any `Binding` problems, you should see what errors are displayed in the Output Window in Visual Studio... they'll tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly.

```
this.MLTBLabel.DataContext = this;
this.MLTBTextBox.DataContext = this;
```

Noooooooooooooooo!

Never. Ever. Ever. Set your `DataContext` from code-behind. As soon as you do this, you lose the magical beauty of binding to your user control's dependency properties from your parent control. In other words, just don't do it.

Here's what you should do:

Give your `UserControl` an `x:Name`.

```
<UserControl ...
    x:Name="usr">
```

Bind your UserControl's Dependency Properties to your elements, like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDependencyProperty, ElementName=usr}" ... />
```

Bind your UserControl's **DataContext** properties to your elements, like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDataContextProperty}"/>
```

Using this method will allow you to set the `DataContext` of your `UserControl` in the `MainWindow`, but still be able to bind to the UserControl's dependency properties within the UserControl. If you set the DataContext of your UserControl in the code-behind, you will not be able to bind to your Dependency Properties.

Now, onto your actual problem.

All of this:

```
private void MLTBTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = this.MLTBTextBox.Text; // transfer changes from TextBox to bindable property (bindable property change notification will be fired)
    }

    private static void LabelTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MyLabelledTextBox)d).MLTBLabel.Content = (string)e.NewValue; // transfer changes from bindable property to Label
    }

    private static void TextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MyLabelledTextBox)d).MLTBTextBox.Text = (string)e.NewValue; // transfer changes from bindable property to TextBox
    }
```

Forget about it. Looks like you're trying to get round the wrongdoings that I spoke about earlier.

You should be binding to your dependency properties instead:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=usr}"/>
```

Another issue that you have is that in your `MainWindow`, you are using a binding on your `UserControl`.

```
Text="{Binding StringData, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Now, as you have already set your `DataContext` in code-behind. What this is effectively saying is:

*Bind to StringData from the DataContext of the current control.*

Which in your case, is a totally different binding from your `MainWindow` DataContext. (As you have explicitly set the DataContext in your UserControl).

Run through what I mentioned earlier. There's a lot to learn, but it's a start.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot understand the lines beginning with “<TextBlock”. In my control “MyLabelledTextBox” I have no TextBlocks, just one TextBox. Should I put the binding in the TextBox like this?

        <TextBox x:Name="MLTBTextBox" ... Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=usr}" />

Comment: Yes that's correct, the code I provided were just examples.

Comment: How will I use the 2nd line starting with “<TextBlock”? You use “TextBlock”, “MyDependencyProperty” and “MyDataContextProperty” as examples, but I introduced a particular TextBox element and a particular dependency property named “TextProperty”. I would prefer to know what to do with these and what new ones to introduce if necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. From what I can gather, all of your elements in your user control need to bind to your dependency property called `Text`.

Comment: There is only one TextBox in my user control and this is the only one that I want to bind to the “Text” dependency property. Then I have a Label there, but it can remain unbound.

Comment: What should I then do to set the binding context?

Comment: It is the responsibility of your Window to set the UserControl's DataContext: `<testBinding:MyLabelledTextBox DataContext="..."`

Comment: What must you do if you have to convert the new value? E.g., `((MyLabelledTextBox)d).MLTBConvertedProperty = ((MyLabelledTextBox)d).ConvertToNew(e.NewValue);`? This issue is not addressed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like its this line:

```
this.StringData = ((this.StringData ?? string.Empty).Length >= 4 ? string.Empty : this.StringData + "*");
    }
```

The first time the timer fires, `this.StringData` is null so the '??' in the expression returns `string.Empty`. It then checks if the length is >= 4. It isnt, so it sets `this.StringData` from null to `string.Empty`. As properties only update on a change, then `INotifyPropertyChanged` fires once.

The second time, we go from `string.Empy` to `string.Empty`, so `INotifyPropertyChanged` does not fire, as there is no change.

Essentially, the timer is firing, but `this.StringData` is now stuck on `string.Empty`, which means `INotifyPropertyChanged` ignores it. This makes sense - why should the WPF runtime go to the trouble of pushing an update from the C# property to the GUI, if the property hasn't actually changed? This would just slow things down for no gain.

This all changes if you use two way binding. If `this.StringData` ever gets set to a length of 4 characters or more, then its away like a racehorse: it will execute the code to append another "*" to it every 10 seconds.

Thus, if you set `this.StringData` to "****" on startup, it will work with OneWay or TwoWay binding, and you will observe the string increasing in length as the timer fires.

Of course, if set to `OneWay` binding, the string will just have a * added to it continuously, and it won't respond to user input. I think of `OneWay` as shorthand for `OneWayFromSource`, so the changes in the C# property will be pushed into the XAML, but any changes from the XAML will not get pushed back into the C#.